# How do I stylize the input type checkbox with the background image

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/dcrysty23/pen/oNGpbZv)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="field choice newsletter">
   <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="Înscrie-te la newsletter" value="1" class="checkbox">
   <label for="is_subscribed" class="label">
   <span>Înscrie-te la newsletter</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0 !important
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label{
  background: url('https://static1.carcloud.ro/static/version1639557414/frontend/Carcloud/default/ro_RO/images/icon-checkbox-a1.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
  color: #23252b;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 26px;
  min-height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: sub
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label span {
  display: inline-block
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background-image: url('https://static1.carcloud.ro/static/version1639557414/frontend/Carcloud/default/ro_RO/images/icon-checkbox-b1.svg')
}
```

I want to change the background when the input is "checked".

Unfortunately this does not happen, something does not work on my CSS code.

Can you please tell me if this can be done as I wanted to write it?

Thank you!

Comment: it seems your checkbox never change state

Comment: Only with CSS??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your input id should be the same as attribute for in label

```
<input type="checkbox" id="is_subscribed" title="Înscrie-te la newsletter" value="1" class="checkbox">
<label for="is_subscribed" class="label">
```